# Trouble removing blank spaces and filling nans in a two column data frame using columns.fillna(column.mean)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove the nans and blank spaces from two columns and replace them with mean values from the respective columns using columns.fillna(column.mean), but it tells me that "columns is not defined" when I implement the following code.

How do I define the columns I've defined as a parameter in my data frame so that the columns.fillna(column.mean) methods apply?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

points = data = pd.read_csv (r'brain_diseases.csv', index_col='id')

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['cancer','prions'])
columns.fillna(cancer.mean())
columns.fillna(pryons.mean())

kpoints = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='random').fit(data)
center = kpoints.cluster_centers_
print(center)

plt.scatter(data['trestbps'], data['chol'], c=kpoints.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(center[:, 0], center[:, 1], c='black', s=50)
plt.show()
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're looking for `df = df.fillna(df.mean())`. Filling NaN values in each column in the dataframe with the corresponding mean from each column, but its a bit unclear without input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`columns` is not defined in your code,

the fillna function can be called on on the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

points = data = pd.read_csv (r'brain_diseases.csv', index_col='id')

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['cancer','prions'])
df.fillna(cancer.mean())
df.fillna(pryons.mean())  # fill on df instead 

...
```

Comment: `cancer` and `pryrons` are undefined in this code. Also [DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) is not inplace by default. `df = df.fillna(cancer.mean())` or `df.fillna(cancer.mean(), inplace=True)`. (assuming `cancer` was defined here)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I see what you both mean. Trying to define cancer and pryons so it reads without traceback rn.